# Shouldn't begin() and end() be callable only for l-value references of class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider follwoing piece of code:

```
struct iterator{};

struct foo {
    iterator begin() &{
        return {};        
    }
    iterator end() &{
        return {};        
    }
};

struct bar {
    iterator begin(){
        return {};        
    }
    iterator end(){
        return {};
    }
};

void baz(){
    //this obviously wouldn't compile
    //vvvvvvvvvvvvv
    //foo().begin();
    bar().begin();
}
```

This is of course toy example, the `foo` and `bar` structs emulate the job of C++ collections. My question is if there are any good arguments to keep the `begin` and `end` functions callable for r-value references (like in `bar`)? Or should I follow the idea from `foo` to make code safer? As far as I know getting iterator from temporary collection is generally bad idea. But on the other hand all collections in STL work both for l- and r-value references so perhaps I am missing something

[live example](https://godbolt.org/z/-xMeh8)

Comment: Note that many `begin()` and `end()` member functions are older than the introduction of rvalue references in C++11. So even if this would be a thoroughly good idea, the Committee would need to consider it against the cost of breaking some existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are thinking of a situation where `begin` is called on a prvalue whose life time ends, so it leads to `foo().begin()` being a dangling pointer, as the temporary `foo()` has been destructed.

But that is not always the case. Just because a value is a prvalue or xvalue does not mean that from call to `foo::begin()` and `iterator::operator*` that the `foo` object will be destroyed or emptied. Consider this:

```
#include <utility>

template<class T> void do_something_with(const T&);

template<class T>
void baz(T&& it) {
    auto begin = std::forward<T>(it).begin();
    auto end = std::forward<T>(it).end();
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        do_something_with(*begin);
    }
}

void bar() {
    baz(foo());
    // Calls `baz<foo>(foo())`, with `decltype(it)` being `foo&&`
}
```

But this is a perfectly valid use case. Don't confuse value type (rvalue or lvalue) with lifetime.